# SSD with a PC - Snazzy use cases?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

What are some off beat use cases I can put my new SSD to work at with a PC.
Pretty happy with my current boot times as well as performance on a standard HDD.

I got this SSD and trying to find something to do with it that is offbeat.
Ideas?

Comment: hmmm....donate it to me? That would be snazzy and offbeat.

Answer (score 1):

Add it as a cache or put your SWAP file on it.

Load a new operating system you have never tried before on it.  Have you ever tried Linux?  If you are familiar with Linux, try a new distro.